# jquery function not invoked from c# code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

i have this jquery function:

```
<script>
    function tabSelected() {
       //alert('tab.');
       $('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show');
    };
</script>
```

this function is called from code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "script", "tabSelected()", true);
```

or:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "tabSelected()", true);
```

none of it works. jquery should be invoked within c# method "ValidateData":

```
private bool ValidateData()
    {
        try
        {
           if (ddlStatusOp.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "script", "tabSelected()", true);

                throw new Exception("'Status' must be selected.");
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw ex;
        }
```

what am i doing wrong with this ?

Comment: Possibly didn't read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  Does the Alert fire if you uncomment it?  Does the F12 Console have any errors?

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're rethrowing the same exception you're catching, you usually just want `throw;`, not `throw ex;` - it will preserve the existing stack trace etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check it that you have a **jQuery** reference like this in the your **head** part of your html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script>
```

after that change your script to this:

```
<script>
    function tabSelected() {
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show');
       });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContainer">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu2">Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu3">Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu4">Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu5">Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabMenu6">Menu 6</a></li>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tabMenu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h2>Menu 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="tabMenu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h2>Menu 2</h2>
</div>
<div id="tabMenu3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h2>Menu 3</h2>
</div>
<div id="tabMenu4" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h2>Menu 4</h2>
</div>
<div id="tabMenu5" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h2>Menu 5</h2>
</div>
<div id="tabMenu6" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h2>Menu 6</h2>
</div>
```

yes, the alert wasn't firing at all, but i managed to solve function call, the problem was in ";" (semicolon) in c# line after "tabSelected()"; the following is correct:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "script", "tabSelected();", true);
```

now the alert is working, but selecting tab using jquery is not working:

```
$('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show');
```

Any help is appreciated.